# Unable to send email via smtp in zend for gmail

Tags: zend-framework

```
       $config = array('ssl' => 'tls',
            'port' => 587,
            'auth' => 'login',
            'username' => '****@gmail.com',
            'password' => '****');
        $tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setBodyText($this->_request->getPost('body'));
        $mail->setFrom('****@gmail.com');
        $mail->addTo($this->_request->getPost('to'), 'receiver1');
        $mail->setSubject('TestSubject');

        if ($mail->send($tr))
            echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
        else
            echo "Mail was not sent";
```

I am getting this error message:

Message: Unable to connect via TLS

Answer (score 0):

You need SSL extension in PHP.

Go to your `php.ini` file on your server, then find `extension=php_openssl.dll` and uncomment it